# Coldfusion: Convert euro date to us date

Tags: coldfusion

I have a date picker sending string dates in Euro format, e.g. 02/12/2011 (December 2, 2011). However, when I try to prepare the date in US format so the database can deal with it, e.g.

```
dateformat(LSDateFormat(form.startDate),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

or

```
dateformat(form.startDate,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

it convolutes the date to 2011-02-12 (February 12, 2011).

Does anyone have a solution that can handle dates - either as strings or date objects.

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the form.startDate has the correct date?  It seems more likely that the date is getting munged on input rather than on output.

Comment: I'm using the native cf datepicker as follows: <cfinput class="dt validate type="datefield" name="startDate" id="startDate" validate="eurodate" mask="dd/mm/yyyy" />

Comment: I just found this related to the datefield type http://www.elliottsprehn.com/cfbugs/bugs/82979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you:

```
<cfscript>
euDateArr = ListToArray(form.startDate, '/');
dateObj = CreateDate(euDateArr[3], euDateArr[2], euDateArr[1]);
</cfscript>
```